# How to get the username domain using wix

Tags: wix

I have developed a screen for admin username and password,how will I display the username and domain automatically in the place of admin name label.Please help me out.. I would like to know whether I should write any custom action for this.

Answer (score 4):

You can access them directly as `[%USERNAME]` and `[%USERDOMAIN]` since both are environment variables.

Comment: +1 but note that `[USERNAME]` is also standard windows installer property, there's no need to use an environment variable for that one.